# NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6) in KNN Algorithm

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

I am trying to predict category based on knn alog. but I don't know why I am getting  above error like "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)" 
I already removed NA values using na.omit(A) function but still getting NA error.

**data.csv**

```
RegionName,RetailerId,PartyName,Address1,Address2,Area,City,ContactPerson,CSTNumber,Email,LicenseNumber,Telephone,MobileNumber
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL & GENERAL STORES,"2,GROUND FLOOR,ABDUL REHAMAN CHAWL,MAROL GAON",SHREE HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD,MAROL,ANDHERI EAST,HARSHIT JAIN,20 Z6 59 90B,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,21 Z6 59 90B,29207788 / 07666464888,"82,864,534,619,867,000,000"
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL [MAROL],"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR RD;MAROL GAON,","ANDHERI[E],MUMBAI-59.",,ANDHERI [E],MR.DINESH KOTHARI,20Z-6-59-908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,21Z-6-59-908,29207788,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL [MAROL],"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR RD;MAROL GAON,","ANDHERI[E],MUMBAI-59.",,ANDHERI [E],MR.DINESH KOTHARI,20Z-6-59-908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,21Z-6-59-908,29207788,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL [MAROL],"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR RD;MAROL GAON,","ANDHERI[E],MUMBAI-59.",,ANDHERI [E],MR.DINESH KOTHARI,20Z-6-59-908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,21Z-6-59-908,29207788,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL & GENRAL STORE,"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD,",MAROL VILLAGE,MAROL,MUMBAI,DINESH,20/Z-6/59/908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,20C/Z-6/59/908,29207788/8286453461,98670976670
MUMBAI,297,$BHAGWATI MEDICAL.,"SHOP NO.2,ABDUL REHMAN CHAWL SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD",,ANDHERI(E),MUMABAI,,20-21-Z-1,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,59-908-20C,29207788/8286453461,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL & GENERAL STORE,SHOP NO.2 ABDUL REHMAN CHAWL  SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR MARG,"MAROL VILLAGE,",,ANDHERI (E),,20/Z-6/59/908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,21/Z-6/59/908,29207788  / 9867097667,7666464888
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MED. & GEN. STORES.,"SHREE HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD, MAROL VILLEG",,MAROL,MUMBAI,DINESH BHIMRAJ,20Z-6/59/908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,20C-Z-6/59/940,29207788,9869260832
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL & GENERAL STORES.,"SHOP NO.2, GR FLOOR, MEZZAINI FLR,ABDULREHMAN CHAWL,","SHREE HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD,MAROL GAON",ANDHERI(E),MUMBAI,,"20,21/Z-6/59/90B",BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,20C/Z-6/59/940,7977458967,9867097667
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL,"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR RD,","MAROL GAON,MAROL, ANDHERI(E)",VP(E)-A(E)-MA,MUMBAI,,"20,21/Z-6/59/908",,20C/Z-6/59/940,29207788,7738788474
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL & GENERAL  STORES.,"SHOP NO.2,ABDUL REHMAN CHWAL,HANUMAN MANDIR,MAROL VILLADGE REZY COELHO CHAWL,",ANDHERI(E),ANDHERI (E),MUMBAI,DINESH BHAI,21Z-6/59/908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,20Z-6/59/908,29207788/7666464888,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MED.& GEN. ST.,2 GR.FL.ABDUL REHMAN CHAWL,HANUMAN MANDIR RD.,MAROL GAON,ANDHERI-E,DINESH KOTHARI,"20,21/Z-6/59/908",BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,20C/Z-6/59/940,9869260832,29207788
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL & GENERAL STORES.,SHOP NO 2.ABDUL REHMAN CHAWL.,"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD, MAROL VILLAGE",MAROL - ANDHERI - EAST,MUMBAI,MAROL,20-Z6/59/908,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,21-Z6/59/908,29207788/7738788474/9869260832,9867097667
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI  MEDICAL,"SHRI   HANUMAN  MANDIR  ROAD,","MAROL  GAON,",ANDHERI (E),MUMBAI,,,,,29207788/8286453461,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDI & GEN.STORES,SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD MAROL VILLAGE,MAROL,,MAROL,,20/Z/6/59/749,,20 C/Z-6/59/788,29207788,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MED ST 29207788,2 GR FL MEZZANIN ABDUL REHAMAN,CHAWLHUMAN MANDIR RDMAROL,ANDHERI,,,27390646287V,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,20-21Z-59-908-20CZ6-59-940,,7666464888
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL,"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD,MAROL GAON,MAROL,ANDHERI-E",,,,,,,,,8286453461
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MED & GEN STORES,,ANDHERI (E),ANDHERI [W],,,,,/,,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL STORE,SH NO.2BRFLR.MAZALIN FLR.,ABDUL REHMAN CHL.HANUMAN MAND,ANDHERI (WEST),,,27390646287 V,BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM,20-21-Z-6-59-90B,9867097667 / 8286453461,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL   MAROL,SHOP NO 2 ABDULREHMAN CHAWL SH,ANDHERI E,,GENERAL,,20/21-Z6-59-908,,20C-Z6-59-940,29207788,
MUMBAI,297,BHAGWATI MEDICAL & GENERAL STORES,"SHRI HANUMAN MANDIR ROAD,, MAROL VILLAGE,, ANDHERI (E),",", MUMBAI.",ANDHERI (E),MUMBAI,,C_00121689190,MUMBAI,20/21-Z-6/59/908,,9867097667
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED.& GEN.ST. #,"22,LAXMI CHAYYA BLDG","L.T.ROAD,BABHAI NAKA",BORIVLI,BORIVALI WEST,8959202,20/Z7/92/2221,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,21/Z7/92/2221,9821287221/28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED & GEN STORES,"22,LAXMI CHHAYA,L.T.ROAD","BABAI NAKA ,EKSAR ROAD",BORIVALI (WEST),MUMBAI,MR CHANDRAKANT,20/Z7/92/2221,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,21/Z7/92/2221,28959202/983381929,9821287221
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MEDICAL & GENERAL STORES,"22, LAXMI CHHAYA, L.T.ROAD",BABHAI NAKA,BORIVALI W,MUMBAI,,20/Z/7/92/2221,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,21/Z/7/92/2221,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,NEW GOPAL KRISHNA MEDICAL & GEN.STORES,"22, LAXMI CHHAYA, BABHAI NAKA",EKSAR ROAD,L.T.ROAD,BORIVALI (W),CHANDHUBHAI,20-MH-MZ7-192791,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,21-MH-MZ7/192792,28959202,9833819296/9821287221
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED.&GEN.STORES,"22,LAXMI CHHAYA,L.T.ROAD,BABHAI","NAKA,WEST MUMBAI",,BORIVALI,CHANDRAKANTBHAI,20Z-7/92/2221,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,21Z-7/92/2221,28959202/69931501,9833819296
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED.& GEN.ST;[BORIVALI-W],"22,LAXMI CHHAYA ,L.T.RD;BHABAI NAKA,","BORIVALI[W],MUMBAI-92.",,BORIVALI [W],MR.CHANDUBHAI,20-Z-7/92/2221,,21-Z-7/92/2221,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED.& GEN.ST;[BORIVALI-W],"22,LAXMI CHHAYA ,L.T.RD;BHABAI NAKA,","BORIVALI[W],MUMBAI-92.",,BORIVALI [W],MR.CHANDUBHAI,20-Z-7/92/2221,,21-Z-7/92/2221,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED.& GEN.ST;[BORIVALI-W],"22,LAXMI CHHAYA ,L.T.RD;BHABAI NAKA,","BORIVALI[W],MUMBAI-92.",,BORIVALI [W],MR.CHANDUBHAI,20-Z-7/92/2221,,21-Z-7/92/2221,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED &. GENERAL STORES,"22, LAXMI CHHAYA BLDG,","BABHAI NAKA, EKSAR RD,",BORIVALI (W),MUMBAI,,20/Z/7/92/2221,,21/Z/7/92/2221,28959202 / 9821287221,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED. & GEN. STORES,"22,LAXMI CHHAYA,","L.T. ROAD,BABHAI NAKA,",,BORIVALI{WEST},,20&21-Z-7/92/2221,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,20C-Z-7/92/2124,"289,592,029,821,287,000",9833819296
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MEDICAL,22LAXMI CHHAYYA,BABHAI NAKA EKSAR ROAD,(S) BORIVALI (WEST).,,,,,20-Z-7/92/187121-Z-7/92/1871 20C-Z-7/92/1817. DT.6.10.08,9821287221/9892695575,
MUMBAI,389,GOPALKRISHNA MEDICAL STORE,,,BORIVALI (WEST),MUMBAI,,,,,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED &. GENERAL STORES,"22, LAXMI CHHAYA BLDG,L.T.RD","BABHAI NAKA, EKSAR RD,",BORIVALI (W),MUMBAI,,20-MH-MZ7-192791,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,21-MH-MZ7-192792,28959202 / 9821287221,
MUMBAI,389,ZZGOPAL KRISHNA MED.ST.,22 LAXMI CHAYA,BABHAI NAKA,L.T.RD,BORIVALI-W,CHANDU BHAI,"20,21/Z-7/92/2221",GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,20C/Z-7/92/2124,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED & GEN STORES,"22,LAXMI CHHAYA, L.T.RD,BABHAI NAKA",,,BORIVALI-W,,"20-Z-7/92/1536,21-Z-7/92/1536",,21-C-Z/92/1481,,
MUMBAI,389,GOPALKRISHNA MEDICAL.,"L.T.ROAD, BABHAI NAKA",BORIVALI (W),,BORIVALI (W),,,,,9821287221,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MEDICAL,"SH-22,L.T.RD,BABAI NAKA",,BORIVALI(W),MUMBAI,,,,,9821287221/28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED.&GEN.STORE,22/LAXMI CHHAYA; L.T.ROAD,BORIVALI  (WEST) BABHAI  NAKA,BORIVALI,,CHANDU BHAI - 9833819296,27480593421V,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,20-Z-7/92/2221*21-Z-7/92/2221 20C-Z-7/92/2124,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA  MED.(CLOSED-,"22,LAXMI CHHAYA,","L.T.ROAD,BABHAI NAKA, BORAVALI WEST,MUMBAI-400092",,BORIVALI- WEST,,20-Z-7/92/1536,,21-Z-7/92/1536,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED & GEN STO,22 LAXMI CHHAYA L T RD,BABHAI NAKABORIVLI W MUM-92,BORIVALI,,9821287221 9892695575,27480593421.V,GOPALKRISHNAMED22@GMAIL.COM,20-21Z7922221 20C2124,28959202,
MUMBAI,389,GOPAL KRISHNA MED & GEN STORE,22/LAXMI CHHAYA,L.T.ROAD,BORIVALI (WEST),,,,,20-7-7/92/1536 /21-Z-7/92/1536,,
```

**RCode**

```
A = read.csv("data.csv")
A = data.frame(na.omit(A))
str(A)
#######
# split training adn testing set
#######
set.seed(123)
sf = sample(2,nrow(A),replace = T,prob = c(0.9,0.1))
trd = A[sf == 1,]
tsd = A[sf == 2,]

# lists out the variables that are problematic
which(sapply(A, function(x) length(unique(x))<2))

# Converts Dependent Variable into Factor
Train_RetailerId = as.factor(trd[,2])

#######
# KNN
#######
library(class)
Predicted.RetailerId = knn(trd,tsd,Train_RetailerId, k=1)

print(mean(A$RetailerId != Predicted.RetailerId))

Result = cbind(Predicted.RetailerId,tsd)

confusionMatrix(Predicted.RetailerId,tsd$RetailerId)
```

**Structure of Dataset**

```
> str(A)
'data.frame':   42 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ RegionName   : Factor w/ 1 level "MUMBAI": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RetailerId   : int  297 297 297 297 297 297 297 297 297 297 ...
 $ PartyName    : Factor w/ 32 levels "$BHAGWATI MEDICAL.",..: 12 15 15 15 14 1 11 5 13 8 ...
 $ Address1     : Factor w/ 36 levels "","2 GR FL MEZZANIN ABDUL REHAMAN",..: 4 32 32 32 34 27 25 29 26 31 ...
 $ Address2     : Factor w/ 31 levels "",", MUMBAI.",..: 29 7 7 7 26 1 27 1 30 25 ...
 $ Area         : Factor w/ 19 levels "","(S) BORIVALI (WEST).",..: 16 1 1 1 16 7 1 16 7 19 ...
 $ City         : Factor w/ 16 levels "","ANDHERI-E",..: 5 4 4 4 16 15 3 16 16 16 ...
 $ ContactPerson: Factor w/ 16 levels "","8959202","9821287221 9892695575",..: 12 16 16 16 8 1 1 10 1 1 ...
 $ CSTNumber    : Factor w/ 26 levels "","20-21-Z-1",..: 8 18 18 18 14 2 14 19 11 10 ...
 $ Email        : Factor w/ 4 levels "","BHAGWATIMEDICAL7@YAHOO.COM",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ LicenseNumber: Factor w/ 30 levels "","/","20-21-Z-6-59-90B",..: 24 28 28 28 14 30 25 11 15 15 ...
 $ Telephone    : Factor w/ 18 levels "","289,592,029,821,287,000",..: 9 7 7 7 12 12 8 7 13 7 ...
 $ MobileNumber : Factor w/ 12 levels "","29207788",..: 5 1 1 1 11 1 3 12 10 4 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the `knn` source code (if you type `knn`) on your console is `train <- as.matrix(train)`, which converts the data.frame to `matrix`. And since a matrix can only contain one data type, it gets converted into a character matrix. Obviously, `knn` and pretty much any other algorithm, requires a numerical matrix in order to run the calculations.

```
trd_mat <- as.matrix(trd)
typeof(trd_mat)
#[1] "character"
```

All of your variables are of type factor and they contain quite a few labels. The only way for it to work is to convert it to dummy variables first (so that it's full of 0-1 variables) and then run knn on that data.frame. Given that your factor variables have plenty of levels, your resulting data.frame will be very sparse which might make knn less efficient.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to convert your factors into dummy variables if you want to follow that route. I link [one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastDummies/vignettes/making-dummy-variables.html).

As an alternative a random forest might give you better results given your factor variables.

Comment: used trd_mat <- as.matrix(trd) but still getiing same error

Comment: I am not saying to run that to fix it. I am proving to you that knn on your existing data set won't work.

Comment: but the dummy variables can cause the wrong prediction on KNN, let me try Random Forest